# Java Mail is sending to Wrong Address

Tags: java, email, gmail

When I am trying to send an email to `pperson@gmail.com` it ends up being sent to `p.person@gmail.com`

---

**Send Email Code:**

```
  String to = "pperson@gmail.com";
  String from = "web@gmail.com";
  String host = "localhost";
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  try{
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
     message.setText("This is actual message");

     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

It works correctly with other emails, why doesn't this one work?

Comment: This Question should be closed because OP forget to give a chance to answer!!!! :)

Comment: @TAsk A man in Sweden kept getting the emails. He told me to stop. Then I found this out, so I thought I would share :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Mail API suggests and states that:

> Gmail doesn't recognize dots as characters within usernames, you can
>   add or remove the dots from a Gmail address without changing the
>   actual destination address; they'll all go to your inbox, and only
>   yours.

**For example:**

- homerjsimpson@gmail.com = hom.er.j.sim.ps.on@gmail.com
- homerjsimpson@gmail.com = HOMERJSIMPSON@gmail.com
- homerjsimpson@gmail.com = Homer.J.Simpson@gmail.com

All these addresses belong to the same person. You can see this if you try to sign in with your username, but adding or removing a dot from it. You'll still go to your account.

---

`Google Apps` does recognize dots. If you'd like to have a dot in your username, please ask your domain administrator to add your preferred username as a nickname.